# Error in dharapvj node module when Angular updated to version 9

Tags: c#, typescript, angular9

I have updated the Angular from 8 to 9 version. When I try to run "ng build", the following exception is occurring:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@dharapvj/ngx-signalr/src/modules/signalr-module.d.ts:11:12
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ɵmod'.
>
> 11     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta;
>                 ~~~~ node_modules/@dharapvj/ngx-signalr/src/modules/signalr-module.d.ts:12:12
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ɵinj'.
>
> 12     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDef;

I am using this npm package: https://github.com/dharapvj/ngx-signalr

I have tried uninstall and reinstall with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After adding flag "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json compilation worked.
This flag skips the build of the d.ts files.

[image: tsconfig]